# Google oAuth2 python application not opening login page online

Tags: python, google-api, gmail, google-oauth, google-api-python-client

I've followed [this document](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python) to create oAuth2 login application.

Created a project and created an oAuth2 client ID as a web application.

[image]

You can see the following code is the same as in the guide. It's working fine on a local machine. Opens the web browser to authenticate, but when I upload it to my hosting. It doesn't open anything. Path where I uploaded to hosting is:

```
public_html/cgi-bin
```

and run script as `python3 quickstart.py`

quickstart.py

```
from __future__ import print_function
import os.path

from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.json.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly']


def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Gmail API.
    Lists the user's Gmail labels.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.json'):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())

    try:
        # Call the Gmail API
        service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)
        results = service.users().labels().list(userId='me').execute()
        labels = results.get('labels', [])

        if not labels:
            print('No labels found.')
            return
        print('Labels:')
        for label in labels:
            print(label['name'])

    except HttpError as error:
        # TODO(developer) - Handle errors from gmail API.
        print('An error occurred: {error}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: InstalledAppFlow opens the consent screen on the machine the code is running on.  its why they tell you at the top of the gmail quick start you followed "Authorization credentials for a desktop application."  if it was designed for hosting they would have told you to create a web app credentials.

Comment: But all other my python applications uploaded to hosting works same as machine. Is there any alternative to InstalledAppFlow which can be used to open consent screen from hosting?

Answer (score 1):

I dont have a gmail web sample on hand.  Here is the relevant chunks from my drive web sample.  The issue is the flow you are using.

```
@app.route('/authorize')
def authorize():
  # Create flow instance to manage the OAuth 2.0 Authorization Grant Flow steps.
  flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.Flow.from_client_secrets_file(
      CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)

  # The URI created here must exactly match one of the authorized redirect URIs
  # for the OAuth 2.0 client, which you configured in the API Console. If this
  # value doesn't match an authorized URI, you will get a 'redirect_uri_mismatch'
  # error.
  flow.redirect_uri = flask.url_for('oauth2callback', _external=True)

  authorization_url, state = flow.authorization_url(
      # Enable offline access so that you can refresh an access token without
      # re-prompting the user for permission. Recommended for web server apps.
      access_type='offline')

  # Store the state so the callback can verify the auth server response.
  flask.session['state'] = state

  return flask.redirect(authorization_url)


@app.route('/oauth2callback')
def oauth2callback():
  # Specify the state when creating the flow in the callback so that it can
  # verified in the authorization server response.
  state = flask.session['state']

  flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.Flow.from_client_secrets_file(
      CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE, scopes=SCOPES, state=state)
  flow.redirect_uri = flask.url_for('oauth2callback', _external=True)

  # Use the authorization server's response to fetch the OAuth 2.0 tokens.
  authorization_response = flask.request.url
  flow.fetch_token(authorization_response=authorization_response)

  # Store credentials in the session.
  # ACTION ITEM: In a production app, you likely want to save these
  #              credentials in a persistent database instead.
  credentials = flow.credentials
  flask.session['credentials'] = credentials_to_dict(credentials)

  return flask.redirect(flask.url_for('test_api_request'))
```

Let me know if you cant figure it out i can see about putting together a sample for gmail.